# mysql Stored Procedure Dynamic Where Clause

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following query in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tempProfile
WHERE 1 = 1
and case    when l_primarymailingaddress = 'address1' then find_in_set(add1_stateid,p_stateid) or p_stateid is NULL
            when l_primarymailingaddress = 'address2' then find_in_set(add2_stateid,p_stateid) or p_stateid is NULL end;
```

I am passing a list of IDs in on p_stateid.

The first case finds matches, but the second case doesn't.

So if, for example, I pass in a 7, I do get back all results that have 7 in add1_stateid, the query is not returning results that have 7 in add2_stateid.

Comparing against every example and description I can find this should work.

Is anyone able to see what I am doing wrong here?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - updated my answer to address where you specifically explained why you were using in_set and P_stateid.  Does breaking the Case statement into two and using an OR to compare each of them work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tempProfile
WHERE 
case when l_primarymailingaddress = 'address1' AND find_in_set(add1_stateid,p_stateid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
OR
case when l_primarymailingaddress = 'address2' AND find_in_set(add2_stateid,p_stateid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
OR
p_stateid is NULL
;
```

2nd update - added another OR to return records when p_stateid is NULL

Comment: Thanks bf2020, no, if I change it to this formI get no results back at all.. regardless of what I pass in on p_stateid (a number, list of numbers or NULL).

Comment: Sorry, disregard previous comment.. It does work if I use your FULL solution, but the problem with this is that part of the requirements are lost.. I get nothing back if I pass in NULL.  I need the query it to ignore this filter entirely if p_stateid is NULL.

Comment: woa.. lucky.. I thought this Q had died.. just noticed your second update after I had deleted.. Thanks bf2020